# How to convert SP to EM?

Tags: android, textview

In API 21, `setLetterSpacing(float)` was introduced. The problem is, the parameter is in **em** units. Many of app graphic designers I've worked with use **sp** to measure their letter spacing. So if I was given

> Letter Spacing: 1.6sp

I usually end up trying out several floating point numbers that will result to something that closely resembles that of the designer's. In short, it's not pixel-perfect.

Do you know of any better way to convert from SP to EM? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources#Dimension) about dimension **SP** behaved like **DP** but for font size. Converting may result in inconsistency based on the screen size and resolution, but here the formula I [found](https://chrisdavies.github.io/sp-to-em/):

```
sp * 0.0624 = em
```

Comment: That's wrong. Only true when the font size is 16sp. Akash Gaonkar's answer is right. The link also converts dp to px 1:1, which is also wrong.

Answer (score 5):

I believe sp and em have different purposes -- sp is used to absolutely size text, while em is for relative sizing. My guess would be that the em letter spacing is some multiple of the size of the text, so if you know the text size, and the desired spacing, the equation would be `spacing_em = spacing_sp / text_size_sp`.

This is just a guess, so please test it and I'll remove the answer if it's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As already provided an answer by Frandall, you can use a simple **sp-em converter** at below link

https://chrisdavies.github.io/sp-to-em/

The formula for converting sp to em is: **sp * 0.0624 = em**

Typical values for slight expansion will be around **0.05**